# Protected sharing over a home network (mac)

Tags: networking, mac, external-hard-drive, file-sharing, password-protection

I have an external drive connected to one of my Mac systems. I was hoping to share that over the home network. We can do so by just going into **System Preference->Sharing->Turning on File Sharing**. However all my files (public directories and external drive data) are visible to all.

I was hoping to place **a few directories on the external drive** with **restricted access** to some users. Is there a quick way to do so?

Just to be clear, I want the external drive to be used as a common storage for all users on the network, but I was hoping a smaller subset of users to have control over some sub-directories on this external drive.

Answer (score 1):

You can be quite specific over which folders/volumes to share & who has what rights…

System Prefs > Sharing > File Sharing …

[image]